# Jboss 5.1 mobicents http response timeout interval

Tags: jboss, mobicents, jain-slee

I 'm using Mobicents http client and I get http requests using GET method.
then I suspend the event using suspendDelivery() and do my work. finally i resume the event using resumeDelivery() and send the http respond.
this is working only less than 10 seconds. when my work is more than 10 seconds jboss close the connection without response.
I increase the connection time out. but it is not solved.

```
  <!-- A HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080 -->
  <Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="8080" address="${jboss.bind.address}" 
           connectionTimeout="200000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Is there another configuration to increase the timeout interval in jBoss 5.1?

Answer (score 0):

You are likely hitting the default event context suspension timeout. According to JAIN SLEE 1.1 FR API documentation for `suspendDelivery`:

> No further SBBs will receive the event until resumeDelivery is invoked on an event context for the same event, **or the system-dependent default timeout is reached**, whichever occurs first.

(emphasis mine)

JAIN SLEE 1.1 FR section 8.3.1 is event more elaborate, detailing that the mandatory timeout is a deliberate safeguard:

> In case of a programming error in the SBB, event delivery is only ever suspended for a time period. This
>   time period can be provided by the SBB as an argument, or if not provided it is a platform specific default.
>   The SLEE automatically resumes the delivery of the event after the period elapses.

The system default is 10 seconds and is controlled by the `defaultEventContextSuspensionTimeout` config property in `$MOBICENTS_HOME/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/mobicents-slee/META-INF/jboss-beans.xml`. But I would suggest to explicitly specify the time limit for suspension that makes sense for a particular service using the `suspendDelivery(int)` call instead of changing the default.